# Get unique/distinct values some properties of PSObjects?

Tags: powershell

The following statement just return one row even if there are multiple distinct rows.

```
import-csv $fname | select "C1", 'C2' | Get-Unique
```

How to get real unique values of the selected `C1` and `C2`?

The problem can be resolved by `-ExpandProperty` if there is only one property selected. I expect it returns the same result of SQL statement `select distinct C1, C2 from ....`.

Comment: I think you mean `-ExpandProperty`. Do you need unique values for the individual properties, or unique combinations?

Comment: I need the unique values of the combinations. Like SQL `select distinct C1, C2 from`.

Comment: `import-csv $fname | select "C1", 'C2' -Unique`

Answer (score 5):

You can achieve this with `Group-Object`:

```
Import-Csv $fname | Group-Object -Property 'C1', 'C2' | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
```

If you need to extract the values, split the `Name` parameter by `,`:

```
$Uniques = Import-Csv $fname | Group-Object -Property 'C1', 'C2' | ForEach-Object { 
    @($_.Name -Split ', ')
}
```

If the properties are not strings, or if they contain commas, you can select the first object from each group:

```
$Uniques = Import-Csv $fname | Select-Object 'C1','C2' | Group-Object -Property 'C1', 'C2' | ForEach-Object { 
    $_.Group | Select-Object -First 1 
}
```

Comment: What if there are commas in `C1` or `C2`?